# How to execute a block of code with 1 second intervals?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, intervals

I need to execute a block every 1 second, but it needs to be in the same thread. This means, from what I understand, that I can't make the use of a timer class.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Is there a reason why Thread.sleep(1000) won't work?

Comment: ...in the same thread as what? As the thread starting the execution or the same thread as the last execution? If the latter is OK, then Timer and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutors are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a thread and write a loop like so -

```
while(true)
{
    // do something
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this loop won't necessarily run every second.  It will sleep for 1 second between iterations.  So, for example, if your task takes 0.5 seconds to complete, then the loop will execute about every 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @rob 

Oh yes, I understand this. This will work more like a timeout function.